# Finding any correlation between curves

Tags: correlation, pattern-recognition

Say i have 2 curves A/B.
I would like to find out the points where at least twice (a pattern) when something happen in A, it affect B.

I dont care what it is, i just look for points of correlation with some signatured behavior.

Is there a simple way to do that? Or only with ML?

See this photo for example.

[image]

Comment: "When something happens in A, it effects B" is not well defined

Comment: That’s the point....I thought using FFT.

Comment: I think you need to spend more time trying to define what you want to do rather than trying to figure out how to do it.